# AngularJS control variable in custom directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I made a custom directive,
and in the template there is a variable ng-model="test",

in the directive controller, 
how can I make any change on the variable?

```
angular.module("myDirective", []).directive("ngTest", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: true,
      template: "<input type='text' ng-model='test'>+
      <button ng-click='change()'></button>",
      controller: function ($scope, $element){
        $scope.change = function(){
          // no idea about how to control variable test here.
          $scope.test = "123123123"; //this doesn't work. :(
        }
      } 
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f8YJ8IAgH5BFUXwc3gr4?p=preview) for you :)

```
app.directive("ngTest", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: true,
      template: "<input type='text' ng-model='test'><button ng-click='change()'>Click Me</button>",
      controller: function ($scope, $element){
        $scope.change = function(){
          // no idea about how to control variable test here.
          $scope.test = "123123123"; //this doesn't work. :(
        }
      } 
    }
  });
```

The problem i find is '+' in directive doesn't work you need to provide complete tempalte in same line or else use tempalteUrl to provide the value to it.

Comment: Glad to help you again :)